# What is sh.reddit.com and old.reddit.com exactly? It's not just a theme

Tags: reddit

What is `sh.reddit.com` and `old.reddit.com` exactly? It's not just a theme.

There seem to be more differences than just the design. For example, I am blocked by `www.reddit.com` because I use a VPN. But not from `old.reddit.com`, which is my workaround for anonymous read access on Reddit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jonathan Tien](https://www.reddit.com/user/ricefield/) ([/u/ricefield](https://www.reddit.com/user/ricefield/) on Reddit), a product manager at Reddit, has indicated that `sh.reddit.com` is slated to be the future default web UI. It appears to be in a testing phase at the moment and is being rolled out to some users, as per various posts about it on Reddit.

> you should give http://sh.reddit.com a try and tell me what you think! (it's our next gen web platform that will soon become the default mweb experience)

- [Jonathan Tien (@ricefield) on X](https://twitter.com/ricefield/status/1414714116493565956)

Relevant Reddit posts:

- [Did Reddit Change The Screen Layout Today?](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/179dzoe/did_reddit_change_the_screen_layout_today/)
- [What is the situation with what seems to be the new user interface redesign and is there a way to avoid it and maintain the "old new Reddit user interface"?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NewToReddit/comments/1b558ul/what_is_the_situation_with_what_seems_to_be_the/)
- [What's going on with the sudden change in reddit UI?](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/19ck0h4/whats_going_on_with_the_sudden_change_in_reddit_ui/)
- [Is sh.reddit now the main interface?](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/17ljiq4/is_shreddit_now_the_main_interface/)

---

The `old.reddit.com` domain redirects users to [Reddit’s classic desktop interface (pre-2018)](https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/2/17190244/reddit-redesign-begins-rolling-out), bypassing any personal settings that might default to the newer layout. Similarly, `new.reddit.com` leads to the current interface. These options ensure that users can access their preferred version of Reddit, regardless of any personal settings.

For those who wish to consistently experience a particular interface, the "[UI Changer for Reddit](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ui-changer-for-reddit/bfcldjodnnkndfccfjndmdlppfkmccgh)" Chrome extension is a handy tool. It automatically redirects all Reddit links to display the chosen interface, be it the classic (`old.reddit.com`), current (`new.reddit.com`), or the "new" new version (`sh.reddit.com`).

As to the VPN blocking, I cannot reproduce the issue. I am not blocked on Reddit when I use a VPN on `old.reddit.com`, `new.reddit.com`, or `www.reddit.com`.